# User.findByID is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am having an issue with node + express routing. I have a routing schema by default provided in the IDE webstorms. I am not sure if I configured everything well, because I am having this error.

I can do a GET /users and POST /users properly with correct results on postman.

routes/users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const _ = require('lodash');
const {ObjectID} = require('mongodb');

const {mongoose} = require('../db/mongoose')
const {User} = require('../db/models/users')
const {Project} = require('../db/models/projects')
const {Dialog} = require('../db/models/dialogs')

(...)

router.get('/users/:userid', (req, res) => {
    var id = req.params.userid.toString();

    if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
        return res.status(404).send();
    }

    User.findByID(id).then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).send();
        }

        res.send({user});
    }).catch(() => {
        res.status(404).send();
    });
});
```

models/users.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

// todo refactor userschema with proper validators (view udemy course)

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: String},
    company: {type: String},
    phone: {type: String},
    projects: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project'}]
});


const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = {User}
```

Comment: JavaScript is [case-sensitive](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch02_02.htm). Try `findById` (emphasis on last character).

Comment: `req.params.userid.toString();` This line may also cause problems, note the lowercase i in `userid`

Answer (score 5):

Mikey is right. Mongoose model function is findById() not findByID() - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I feel really stupid with this. Actually, webstorms ide, suggests using findByID: https://pasteboard.co/H0jrCRO.png